# How to speed-up a spatial join in BigQuery?

Tags: performance, join, google-bigquery, spatial-query

I have a BigQuery table with point registers along a whole country, and I need to assign a "censal zone" to each one of them, which polygons are contained in another table. I've been trying to do so using a query like this one:

```
SELECT id_point, code_censal_zone
    FROM `points_table`
    JOIN `zones_table`
    ON ST_CONTAINS(zone_polygon, point_geo)
```

The first table is quite large, so the query performes very inefficiently as it is comparing each possible pairs of (point, censal zone). However, both tables have a column identifier for the municipality in which they are in, so the question is, can rewrite my query in some way that `ST_CONTAINS(*)` is performed for each (point, censal zone) pair that belongs to the **same** municipality, hence not comparing all posible censal zones within the country for each point? Can I do this without having to read `points_table` multiple times?

```
SELECT id_point, code_censal_zone
    FROM `points_table`
    JOIN `zones_table`
    ON 1.municipality = 2.municipality
    AND ST_CONTAINS(zone_geo, point_geo)
```

I'm quite new to BigQuery so I don't really know if a query like this would actually do what I'am expecting, as I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried the last query and it actually computes faster, but I'm still a bit lost about why is that. Is this because the first condition is computed first and if it returns false, ST_CONTAINS() isn't computed?

Comment: The second query should work fine. As for the question in your comment: Data is being accessed from an index via either a scan or a seek. A seek is a targeted selection of rows from the table based on a narrow filter. A scan is when an entire index is searched to return the requested data. This means that if a table contains a million rows, then a scan will need to traverse all million rows to service the query. But if you use Index it will return only the data needed, without the need to inspect the entire table.

Comment: Since this is passing less data this computes faster you can see here the [factors of query performance](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview#query_performance).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand that by using the `municipality` column I'm effectively comparing few rows of data, because I'm making use of an Index. What if, for example, I switch the order of the join conditions like `ST_CONTAINS(zone_geo, point_geo) AND 1.municipality = 2.municipality`, or If I use an `OR` operator instead of `AND`?. Would those queries still benefit from using Index?

Comment: If you switch the order of the condition it will be the same because you are still searching by an `index`, if you use an `OR` operator it will take more time because it will take more time because it will search by index and by `ST_CONTAINS` if one of those is valid it will compute more rows. When you use an `AND` both of the conditions needs to be valid to bring the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id_point, code_censal_zone
    FROM `points_table`
    JOIN `zones_table`
    ON 1.municipality = 2.municipality
    AND ST_CONTAINS(zone_geo, point_geo)
```